# How can I call function names from flat file in c++

Tags: c++

I need an opinion on how the following can be done using C++ and also the design approach.

I am trying to develop an automated process reading key-value pairs from flat file where value represents function names which are already defined in the c++ program. This is to automatically map the future product keys.

I am trying to store the keys - function names in a flat file as a mapping to avoid any code change.

This is what I got so far.

Flat File Contents:

```
CLO|LINK_CURRENT_BALANCE|getLinkBalance(double icm, double pip, string keyFld)
CLO|FORBER_CURRENT_BALANCE|getForberBalace(double icm, double pip, string keyFld)
```

C++ code sample:

```
std::map<std::string, std::function<int(double icm, double pip, string key)>>  funcMap1 =
{
    {"getLinkBalance", getLinkBalance},
    {"getForberBalace", getForberBalace}
};

vector<string> fldV;
//read file until EOF reached
while(!infile.eof())
{
    getline(infile, sLine);
    fldV = split(sLine.c_str(), '|');

    string prtType = fldV[0];//product
    string fldTag = fldV[1]; //key fld
    string stype = fldV[2]; //formula name

    //std::cout << funcMap1[stype.c_str() ](icmop, pip, fldTag)   << "\n"; //not    working

    std::cout << funcMap1["getLinkBalance"](icmop, pip, fldTag) << "\n";
}

infile.close();

std::cout << funcMap1[stype.c_str() ](icmop, pip, fldTag) << "\n";
```

In the last statement, the `stype` doesn't work. I had to hardcode the function name. How to address this?

Comment: Start out formatting your code in question please.

Comment: If you do a `std::cout << stype;`, what do you get? Also you don't need to do `funcMap1[stype.c_str()]` since the key type in your function mapping is `std::string`. Just do `funcMap1[stype]`.

Comment: vector<string> fldV;
while (!infile.eof())
{
 getline(infile, sLine);
 fldV = split(sLine.c_str(), '|');

 string prtType = fldV[0];//product
 string fldTag = fldV[1]; //key fld
 string stype = fldV[2]; //formula name

 //std::cout << funcMap1[stype.c_str() ](icmop, pip, fldTag)   << "\n"; //not    working
 std::cout << funcMap1[stype ](icmop, pip, fldTag)   << "\n"; //not    working
 std::cout << funcMap1["getLinkBalance"](icmop, pip, fldTag) << "\n";
}
infile.close();
If I hardcode the function name it works. otherwise its going into error mode.

Comment: I never claimed that `funcMap1[stype]` will fix your problem. It's just not necessary to cast to a `c_str` when it'll get pushed back into a `std::string` anyway. At any rate, see my answer below, I've found your problem.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you do the split against `|`, you get three strings:

```
"CLO"
"LINK_CURRENT_BALANCE"
"getLinkBalance(double icm, double pip, string keyFld)"
```

Which clearly isn't what you want. You need to take the third string you get and find the opening parenthesis:

```
string stype = fldV[2]; //formula name
stype = stype.substr(0, stype.find("("));
```

This should give you the correct function name.